# Android WebView shows diamond question marks for spanish letters

Tags: encoding, webview

I know this question has been asked before but I checked all the answers and non worked for me.
I'm reading the html from a file like this

```
StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(mContentPath)), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileData.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        reader.close();
        content = fileData.toString();
```

and then I load it like this

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I have tried to use

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

as well as changing the text/html to text/html; charset=UTF-8

But none of these worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it wasn't UTF-8 :)
I used firefox to figure out what encoding it is and it showed it as western.
I changed the encoding of the reading to "ISO-8859-1" which showed it almost as expected, but close enough to what I need.